# Handling escape characters when calling `request.get(...).json()`

Tags: python, json

I'm working with a third party API that will include HTML escape characters within the response, which is causing an error of `Expecting ',' delimiter:` when calling the below:

```
request_get = request.get(...)
request_get.json()
```

I've filtered down the error to the simplest form below to show an example of what the error is coming from. Note that request_get in this case is a request object:

```
request_get = """{
  "text": {
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"></div>"
  }
}"""
json.loads(request_get)
```

Output:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 25 (char 38)
```

What is the best way to deal with this type of return? Note the error comes from `\"`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The backslashes in your data aren't literal -- they get removed during Python parsing before the assignment to `request_get` even happens. So you have an incorrect string that doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: Run `print(request_get)` after running the assignment in the question and you'll see the problem. Change it to `request_get = r"""{` and you'll no longer have that problem.

Comment: Assuming this is something that's really coming from an external server then, either that server isn't returning JSON, or the assignment given in the question doesn't actually evaluate to the data your server is giving you. I'm guessing the latter, but right now that's just a guess.

Comment: use single or triple quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you can use raw string format (by prefixing the string with r) to ensure the escape characters are treated as literals

```
import json

request_get = r"""{
  "text": {
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"></div>"
  }
}"""

data = json.loads(request_get)
print(data)
```

output:

```
{'text': {'div': '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></div>'}}
```

Comment: yeah, sure. That sentence is not necessaryy